# C - Designated Initializer (xv6)

Tags: c++, c, lambda

I'm recently taking Operating System course, where we study xv6. During practice lab I ran into the code like below:

```c
// xv6_public/syscall.c
#include "defs.h"
#include "syscalls.h"
...

extern int sys_fork(void);

...

static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
    [SYS_fork]    sys_fork,
    ...
};
```

I didn't recognize the syntax used above at all at first. After searching the net I found that the syntax is called **Lambda function**, but I still have questions:

1. Many articles say it is available to use Lambda only with C++. Is it able to use Lambda in C? Is syntax the same as that of C++? (the source files are all `.c`, probably compiler is g++)
2. Would someone briefly explain the code above? I can understand that it is function pointer array where each element is lambda function. Or please recommend nice reference to read.

Comment: And that's not valid lambda syntax. Missing parameter list and body.

Comment: @Mat Nice forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not C++ lambdas, instead it's standard C99 [array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) using *designated initializers*.

The value inside the square brackets (e.g. `[SYS_fork]`) is a compile-time integer constant and designates the index in the array for the initialization.